# better way to find records based on junction object field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm new to rails and trying to see if there's a more efficent way to find locations based on a field set in the junction object. The relationship is events have many locations through events_locations. Here's a simplified example:

```
@locations=[]
events_locations = @event.events_locations.where(:fieldvalue=>1)
events_locations.each do |el|
  @locations<<Location.find(el.location_id)
end
```

It seems wasteful and could generate a lot of queries. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess fieldvalue is a field of events_locations, then

```
class Event
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end

@locations = @event.locations.where(events_locations: {fieldvalue: 1})
```

Comment: your assumption was correct, thanks! Can you suggest any good sites where I can find snippets like this?